# OdbcException occurs when using the OdbcDataReader.GetName method

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, oracle, odbc

I'm migrating from oracle to sqlserver.
So, changing from OracleDataReader to OdbcDataReader.

I'd like to get the name of a column using the GetName method.(Using the mysub subroutine.)

but, using the getName method occurs in an ODBCException.

> ERROR [HY007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Associated statement is not prepared

I thought that it would occur if OdbcDataReader was passed as an argument, but even if written in the main function it will occur the same way.

And if you write as follows, one getName method raises an exception, the other can get the column name correctly.

In this example it is simple SQL, but in fact there are various SQL settings.

However, since all SQL is not escaped, I think that a prepared statement is unnecessary.

It worked properly in Oracle. Why does this happen?

Please tell me how to resolve.

```vb
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim connection As OdbcConnection = Nothing
        Try
            'Set Connection String.
            Dim constr As String = "Provider=MSDASQL; DSN=myDSN; UID=myDBUSR; PWD=myPass;"
            connection = New OdbcConnection(constr)

            'DB Open.
            connection.Open()

            'Begin Transaction
            Dim tran As OdbcTransaction = connection.BeginTransaction

            'Set SQL Command
            Dim command As OdbcCommand = connection.CreateCommand()
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[TBL01]"
            command.CommandTimeout = 1200
            command.Transaction = tran

            'ExecuteSQL
            Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

            'Get column names with other functions.
            mySub(reader)

            'Get data with the main function
            Dim colName As String = reader.GetName(0)   ' -> Exception Occurd.
            'ERROR [HY007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Associated statement is not prepared


            'some logics...

            tran.Commit()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Trace.TraceInformation(ex.Message & vbCrLf)
            Trace.TraceInformation(ex.StackTrace)
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub mySub(ByVal reader As OdbcDataReader)
        Dim colName As String = reader.GetName(0)   ' -> Exception Occurd.
        'ERROR [HY007] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Associated statement is not prepared

        Trace.TraceInformation(colName)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Why do you use ODBC? I think [System.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient?view=netframework-4.5) will work better as it is dedicated to SQL-Server. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b1cf6249-cbc2-4ab7-90d9-dbea8acf523a/what-is-the-difference-between-systemdatasqlclient-systemdataoledbclient-and?forum=sqldataaccess

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit 
It is because the customer decided it. I have no authority to change.
I will consult customer .

Comment: Why are you wrapping a `SELECT` statement into a transaction? What are you expecting to happen in the `.Commit` statement?

Comment: @Olaf I can not understand either. This is the first thing written by the person who created this program. Although it is necessary to investigate, it seems that only the SELECT statement will probably come. Is this error when setting a transaction in the SELECT statement?